# Select form changes, pop up alert then send form

Tags: jquery, forms, select, onchange

i used the answer given on this link by Greg Hornby "[When html select form changes, pop up alert then send form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275959/when-html-select-form-changes-pop-up-alert-then-send-form)"
it works good but for one issue the select box still changes even if we press the cancell button, it does not save the change but it does show changed if we refresh the page it reverts back but for a moment when we change the select box it shows changed, 
My question is how can we prevent the select box change if we press cancel

My code is

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="payment_status" class="form-control status_select" onchange="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Change this Status?')){this.form.submit()}">
 <option value="">Select Payment Status</option>
 <option value="Un paid">Un-paid</option>
 <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop()` to set the selected option to `false` in the `else` statement:

```js
$("select").change(function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Change this Status?')){
        {this.form.submit()} 
    }
    else $("select option:selected").prop("selected", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="payment_status" class="form-control status_select">
 <option value="">Select Payment Status</option>
 <option value="Un paid">Un-paid</option>
 <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: "we prevent the select box change" this does not means "change to default value"

Comment: This works very good, but i am using this select box with the values selected using php, so what this does is change the value to the selectedIndex=0
is there any way that we can keep the values selected according to php and not to select the 0 index

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, set the initial state to a variable, then on confirmed change, update that variable. On cancel, reset the value to previously confirmed or initial state, like this:

```
<script>
var initial = '<?php echo "Paid"; ?>'; 
function reset(){ $("select").val(initial); }
</script>
```

and onChange if confirmed, then submit, else reset()